# what is rtnetlink(linux os), what is difference between netlink and rtnetlink?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to modifying the kernel routing table,but I don't what to do.I browsed some books about linux,but I got nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jww: Both "netlink" and "rtnetlink" terms are primary intended for programming, so asking about them is **on-topic** on Stack Overflow. (That doesn't mean that the question doesn't fall into other close-reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NETLINK` is the method for the userspace program to talk to kernel space.
`RTNETLINK` is one of type of netlink family. You can imagine that you are sending message to the kernel routing module. You may refer to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html